# Two modems - bridge internet speeds to groups of IP?

Tags: networking, router, internet

Stuck with a bit of a pickle here and wondering about what hardware options are available for my current problem. But first, let me explain whats happening and what I want to do before you suggest an answer

---

**Current Prediciment**

We have 5 customers in a rural area who have no access to DSL internet in their location. There isn't any alternative connection for them actually. The closest down, about 20 miles away has DSL available with a maximum data package of 5 mbps download and 1 mbps upload. The first customer, we will call them Customer A, can see the town, where-as the other 4 customers cannot, BUT they can see the first Customers house (Geographical limitations). They are using a Point-2-Point internet hop from the town to Customer A, then a different Point-2-Multipoint hop from Customer A to Customers B, C, D, and E. This leaves all of the customers sharing a single connection back in the original town. You can see the problem here already, if Customer E watches Netflix, goodbye data speeds to everyone else. Below is a current map of the network as it stands

```
► ISP Supplied internet AP in town (64.x.x.x)
   ► to router (192.168.1.1)
      ► to first inet hop AP (192.168.1.2) -> to SM (192.168.1.3)
        ► From SM to switch
           ► Switch to router at Customer A (192.168.1.4)
           ► Switch to second AP for Customers B,C,D,E (192.168.1.5)
              ► AP to Customer B (192.168.1.6)
              ► AP to Customer C (192.168.1.7)
              ► AP to Customer D (192.168.1.8)
              ► AP to Customer E (192.168.1.9)
```

---

**Suggested Solution**

Is there a managed switch or routing system I can put before the very first AP hop (replacing 192.168.1.1) that I can plug more then one ISP supplied internet into (Multiple WAN ports) that I can direct traffic from 192.168.1.4/7 too and 192.168.1.8/9 to the other modem? In essence, plug two 5 mbps links into it and shape it so that the customers can share it like a 10 mbps connection? I'd like to be able to plug in essence a modem for each customer in and then direct all their traffic to their own dedicated line if that makes sense that way they aren't sharing but since that't probably not possible and as far as I know you can't join two 5 mbps modems to make a single 10 mbps connection, I am wondering what options there are.

I was pointed towards this router here as a possibility:

https://mikrotik.com/product/RB750GL

I am unsure of if that is what I am looking for or not. This question isn't really about preference or brand, I don't care about that, I just want to know if what I am asking is possible and what type of equipment I will need to make it work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want each customer to have their own modem/connection from the ISP in the town or are wanting them to share multiple connections.  I believe either one is possible, but the setup is very different.  Also, make sure you've considered the bandwidth of your wireless links before you go get a bunch of bandwidth from the ISP that you can't carry over the wireless link.

Comment: Eventually would like them to all have their own connection from the ISP in town yes but since the internet hope in bridged mode only has on channel and one Ethernet cable to it, I need to manage which ip goes to which modem. The wireless links are currently transporting 80mbps down and 87mbps up on 5mHz band at their distance so that won’t be a bottle neck for them. I need to do exactly what you asked lol

Comment: Just thought of this need your input. Currently the internet hops are all set to bridge connections so they just pass through data. If I plug two modems with different ips in the town into a switch and then the master AP into the switch, since it’s in bridged mode, if I set static routes at customer a and b to use connection to gateway of modem one and customers c, d, etc use modem two as gateway with same netmask of 255.255.255.0 would it cause network interference or work? I’ll have to try testing that but that seems too easy to work haha

Comment: If you are going to statically route specific customers to a certain modem, then I would set them up in different IP ranges, so you'll essentially have 2 subnets on one physical network.

Comment: Yeah I’d do modem one to 192.168.1.1 andmodem two to 192.168.2.1 both with subnets of 255.255.255.0 but since they would be plugged into the same switch, would it cause network conflicts? Or can I do that and statically specify the router I want to use with the router at the customers houses without network issues. Thanks

Comment: You should be able to do that without any problems.

Comment: So while this did work, once I added the internet hop in there’s a bottleneck — the connection across the linkhardware can’t handle multiple data streams and VLAN setup doesn’t seem to work. The first SM connects but then the AP is busy because it’s serving the first IP range so the second one gets rejected during tests. I’ll need a way to pool them so my wireless hop works as a tunnel and can pass all the network traffic properly.